# Merge changes from shelved CLN into open files

Tags: version-control, perforce

I have a shelved CLN with 2 files in it. I also have a default CLN open in my workspace with 2 files in it. There is one file in common between the two CLNs. I am trying to unshelve my shelved CLN changes and was hoping perforce would be able to perform a merge on the changes in the common file. But it simply says that the file is already open and it cannot be unshelved. The command I am using is:

p4 unshelve -s cln -c cln

Is there a way to have my shelved changes merged into my already open file?

Comment: `p4 unshelve -s CLN -c CLN` works for me.  Are you sure that the file wasn't made writable without actually opening it for edit in the default changeset?  What is the exact error message that you get?

Comment: No, I opened the file for edit using p4 and then made changes to it. The error message I get is: //path/to/file - can't unshelve (already opened for edit)

Comment: Strange.  What version of the Perforce server and client are you using?

Comment: Server version: P4D/LINUX26X86_64/2009.2/232252 (2010/01/27)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ability to unshelve into opened files (and resolve the changes) was added in release 2011.1. Can you upgrade your server?

Comment: Oh I see. Too bad I can't do that. Guess I'll have to start looking for workarounds. You know any? Scripts?

Comment: @IM42: You could manually merge them by generating a diff from one of the changesets and applying it with `patch`.